# heroku logs --tail error message: Local server works, but Heroku doesn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I keep getting this error message. I've tried 50 different ways to solve it but no luck. I am also having a hard time just understanding what the error is. Thank you in advance for any love!

```
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126017+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126014+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126018+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126013+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.125976+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126020+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126026+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126024+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126035+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126041+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126037+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.125995+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126023+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.126042+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-12-21T23:32:05.931736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-12-21T23:32:05.921721+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-12-21T23:36:07.676326+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v9 created by xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2014-12-21T23:36:07.676298+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9a08d09 by xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
2014-12-21T23:36:07.827584+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2014-12-21T23:36:11.853325+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 25861 -e production`
2014-12-21T23:36:14.746043+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2014-12-21T23:36:14.746066+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.0.rc3 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:25861
2014-12-21T23:36:14.746069+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2014-12-21T23:36:14.746071+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2014-12-21T23:36:14.746073+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747382+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747377+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/controllers/devise_controller.rb:13:in `<class:DeviseController>': undefined local variable or method `mimes_for_respond_to' for DeviseController:Class (NameError)
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747387+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747384+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747389+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747393+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747394+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747398+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in `load_missing_constant'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747401+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/devise-3.4.0/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747409+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747405+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747407+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747425+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747412+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747430+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747429+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747431+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:472:in `block (2 levels) in eager_load!'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747437+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `block in eager_load!'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747435+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:471:in `each'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747449+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747441+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `eager_load!'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747454+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747460+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:150:in `block in tsort_each'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747440+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:469:in `each'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747445+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/engine.rb:346:in `eager_load!'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747446+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:56:in `each'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747456+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747451+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747461+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:183:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747462+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:219:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747467+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747466+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:182:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747476+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747500+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747471+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:180:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747503+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747477+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747472+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tsort.rb:148:in `tsort_each'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747479+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747496+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747502+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.0.rc3/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747506+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747504+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747514+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `eval'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747507+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747511+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `new'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747512+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747515+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747528+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747524+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:336:in `wrapped_app'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747520+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:299:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747521+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:208:in `app'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747530+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747516+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747533+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747543+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747536+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747527+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.6.0/lib/rack/server.rb:272:in `start'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747534+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747539+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.2.0.rc3/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2014-12-21T23:36:14.747540+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:8:in `require'
2014-12-21T23:36:15.581730+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-12-21T23:36:15.589824+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2014-12-21T23:36:16.415280+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate` by anthonygalli.com@gmail.com
2014-12-21T23:36:19.814074+00:00 heroku[run.5090]: Awaiting client
2014-12-21T23:36:19.840853+00:00 heroku[run.5090]: Starting process with command `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-12-21T23:36:20.345366+00:00 heroku[run.5090]: State changed from starting to up
2014-12-21T23:36:24.110001+00:00 heroku[run.5090]: Process exited with status 0
2014-12-21T23:36:24.123483+00:00 heroku[run.5090]: State changed from up to complete
2014-12-21T23:36:41.983845+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=rule-today.herokuapp.com request_id=fed24950-d302-46b1-8361-a94c4a4fcef5 fwd="73.0.11.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-12-21T23:36:43.256151+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rule-today.herokuapp.com request_id=3cf8849a-4750-4a24-9cc5-ff6c1b0c7b5d fwd="73.0.11.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-12-21T23:36:43.641459+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rule-today.herokuapp.com request_id=f1f36122-99d6-41d8-8df9-a88f52572360 fwd="73.0.11.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-12-21T23:36:43.789730+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rule-today.herokuapp.com request_id=88861f5f-5b5a-491b-a168-db35a4b54549 fwd="73.0.11.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-12-21T23:36:43.796995+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=rule-today.herokuapp.com request_id=17a1d09f-fd4d-49d6-901b-3a56b15f8f0f fwd="73.0.11.102" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried?

Comment: I'm new to this, but a bunch of little stuff. I kept doing various migrations and resets and altering code and taking code out and at this point I'm still at square one. Sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: Just a little side note, but next time you post logs, it would be a good idea to filter out your actual email address. Spam bots are always hungry for email addresses.

Comment: have you tried `bundle update responders` as suggested in this bug report: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/3160 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running

```
$heroku run rails console
```

in the terminal, this should point out some of your errors, then go back into your text editor to fix them.